# How to Extract XML table data using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

```
<table index="1" title=" Final year marks of BIT students" ref="BIT results">
        <headings>
          <heading>Semester1</heading>
          <heading>Semester2</heading>
          <heading>Semester3</heading>
          <heading>Semester4</heading>
          <heading>Grade</heading>
          <heading>FYP</heading>
        </headings>
        <tablebody>
          <tablerow>
            <tablecell><item>10</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>12</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>13</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>15</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>B</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>B</item></tablecell>
          </tablerow>
        </tablebody>
      </table>
      <table index="2" title="Final year marks of COM students" ref="COM results">
        <headings>
          <heading>Semester1</heading>
          <heading>Semester2</heading>
          <heading>Semester3</heading>
          <heading>Semester4</heading>
          <heading>Grade</heading>
          <heading>FYP</heading>
        </headings>
        <tablebody>
          <tablerow>
            <tablecell><item>15</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>15</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>15</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>14</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>A</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>A</item></tablecell>
          </tablerow>
          <tablerow>
            <tablecell><item>10</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>5</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>9</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>11</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>C</item></tablecell>
            <tablecell><item>C</item></tablecell>
          </tablerow>
        </tablebody>
      </table>``
```

Hi, I'm new to Xpath. I need to extract XML table data with using Xpath. Here is my XML code. I  have tried, but couldn't get a successful output.

```
The output table would be like this 

semester1  semester2  semester3 semester4  grade  fyp
 10            11          13       12         A   B
```

Does anyone have any idea the best way to approach this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

To start with, your example XML is invalid.  Either you've supplied two separate examples, or you're missing the surrounding parent tags.

I assumed the second and wrapped you examples in `<tables></tables>` tags.

So now based on this...

```
<tables>
    <table index="1" title=" Final year marks of BIT students" ref="BIT results">
        <headings>
            <heading>Semester1</heading>
            <heading>Semester2</heading>
            <heading>Semester3</heading>
            <heading>Semester4</heading>
            <heading>Grade</heading>
            <heading>FYP</heading>
        </headings>
        <tablebody>
            <tablerow>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>10</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>12</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>13</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>15</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>B</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>B</item>
                </tablecell>
            </tablerow>
        </tablebody>
    </table>
    <table index="2" title="Final year marks of COM students" ref="COM results">
        <headings>
            <heading>Semester1</heading>
            <heading>Semester2</heading>
            <heading>Semester3</heading>
            <heading>Semester4</heading>
            <heading>Grade</heading>
            <heading>FYP</heading>
        </headings>
        <tablebody>
            <tablerow>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>15</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>15</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>15</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>14</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>A</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>A</item>
                </tablecell>
            </tablerow>
            <tablerow>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>10</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>5</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>9</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>11</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>C</item>
                </tablecell>
                <tablecell>
                    <item>C</item>
                </tablecell>
            </tablerow>
        </tablebody>
    </table>
</tables>
```

I was able to use...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class TestXPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new File("Table.xml"));

            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath path = xFactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression exp = path.compile("/tables/table");
            NodeList nlTables = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int tblIndex = 0; tblIndex < nlTables.getLength(); tblIndex++) {

                Node table = nlTables.item(tblIndex);
                Node nAtt = table.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title");
                System.out.println("Showing results for " + (nAtt == null ? "[Unknown]" : nAtt.getTextContent()));

                exp = path.compile("headings/heading");
                NodeList nlHeaders = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(table, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                Set<String> headers = new HashSet<String>(25);
                for (int index = 0; index < nlHeaders.getLength(); index++) {
                    headers.add(nlHeaders.item(index).getTextContent().trim());
                }

                for (String header : headers) {
                    System.out.printf("%-20s", header);
                }
                System.out.println("");

                exp = path.compile("tablebody/tablerow");
                NodeList nlRows = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(table, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int index = 0; index < nlRows.getLength(); index++) {
                    Node rowNode = nlRows.item(index);
                    exp = path.compile("tablecell/item");
                    NodeList nlValues = (NodeList) exp.evaluate(rowNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(25);
                    for (int valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < nlValues.getLength(); valueIndex++) {
                        values.add(nlValues.item(valueIndex).getTextContent().trim());
                    }
                    for (String value : values) {
                        System.out.printf("%-20s", value);
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

To produce...

```
Showing results for  Final year marks of BIT students
Semester1           Semester2           Semester3           Semester4           FYP                 Grade               
10                  12                  13                  15                  B                   B                   

Showing results for Final year marks of COM students
Semester1           Semester2           Semester3           Semester4           FYP                 Grade               
15                  15                  15                  14                  A                   A                   
10                  5                   9                   11                  C                   C
```

Basically, you need to be able to break down each section into manageable parts...

Take a look at [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) and read just about every post on SO about XPath ;)

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your feedback on my program. I will test this out and I'll let you know how it goes.
Regards.